# How to make Laravel's Notification throw an Exception in test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, laravel-5.5

I have a few laravel commands that inherit from my own class to send slack messages if they fail. However if the slack notification fails I still want the original exception thrown so that the error still ends up in the logs if slack is unavailable or misconfigured. I have this and it works, but I can't figure out how to trigger an exception in the Notification part in tests.

```php
namespace App\Support;

use App\Notifications\SlackNotification;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CarrotCommand extends Command
{   
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)                  
    {
        try {
            return parent::execute($input, $output);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->notifySlack($e);

            throw $e;
        }
    }


    protected function notifySlack(\Exception $e)
    {
        try {
            Notification::route('slack', config('app.slack_webhook'))->notify(
                new SlackNotification(
                    "Error\n" . get_class($e) . ': ' . $e->getMessage(),
                    'warning'
                )
            ); 
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {

            // I want to reach this part in a test

            $this->error(
                'Failed to send notice to slack: ' . $exception->getMessage()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As `Notification::route` is defined on the facade I can't use `Notification::shouldReceive` to trigger the exception and the `SlackNotification` is newed up making it difficult to mock.

Any ideas as to how I can trigger an exception?

Comment: You have 2 try/catch blocks in that execute() function and you make return right away in first try/catch... you will get inside second try/catch only if parent::execute() throws an error. It's a little bit messy code you've got...

Comment: I have no problem reaching the first catch block by triggering an exception in `handle` of an inheriting class, the problem is triggering an Exception within that catch block. I'll try to clean up the code a bit...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FlorianFalk, sorry I don't remember and I no longer have access to the source code so I can't check what I did in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody's still wondering how to do this, you can mock `Notification::send` like:

```php
Notification::shouldReceive('send')
  ->once()
  ->andThrow(new \Exception());
```

Comment: I no longer have access to the code base I was working on then so I can't test it, but having worked with Laravel for a few more years I realize that `Notification` is a `Facade` so it should have testing facilities built in.